# Symfony 4 get request issue

Tags: php, json, symfony, request, symfony4

I'm trying to get a simple raw `json-application` request in a simple service instantiated in `symfony 4` but it seems different from `symfony 3`.

My route

```
deposit_money:
    path:     /auth/money/deposit
    methods: [POST]
    controller: App\Controller\MoneyController::deposit
    defaults:
        _format: json
```

My controller

```
public function deposit(MoneyService $moneyService)
{
    $moneyService->depositMoney();

    return new JsonResponse(
        'Money sent bla bla', JsonResponse::HTTP_NO_CONTENT
    );
}
```

My service:

```
class MoneyService
{
    /** @var EntityManagerInterface */
    private $entityManager;

    /** @var RequestStack */
    private $requestStack;

    /**
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
     * @param RequestStack $requestStack
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }

    public function depositMoney()
    {
         $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->setRequestFormat('json');

        var_dump($this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->getContent());

    }
}
```

My *raw* Request `JSON(application/json)`

```
{
    "depositAmount":4
}
```

No problem so far, I send the request and it's perfectly received but...
In `symfony 3` when I wanted to get the request parameter, it was enough something like this

```
$this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->get('depositAmount')
```

whereas in this new service in `symfony 4`, I first need to grab the request content in this way getting exactly the same raw json string sent with PostMan.

```
$this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->getContent()
```

Will follow json conversion etc...

So my question is...
Is there a way to grab the parameter as simply as doing somethig like

```
$this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->get('depositAmount')
```

Is there something I have missed or now I need to inject the serialize into the service and convert everything?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Sf4 application its not parsing json content. A Subscriber like that may help you: [JsonBodyParserSubscriber](https://github.com/jorge07/symfony-4-es-cqrs-boilerplate/blob/master/src/UI/Http/Rest/EventSubscriber/JsonBodyParserSubscriber.php#L15)